# How to load properties file in maven webapp using File object?

Tags: java, maven, web-applications, classpath

Method

```
getResourceAsStream
```

Works fine but I need to check as well was file modified or not. This is a reason to use  File object. I cant achieve this goal.

```
File file = new File("goods.props")
```

Works fine in JUnit environment, but in webapp I get an FileNotFoundException.

In fact I insert into code loading props file next lines:

```
File file = new File(".")
Sysout(file.getAbsolutePath())
```

In JUnit environment console output is:

```
C:\Users\developer\workspace\Projects\WebApp\.
```

which is correct

But when I start webapp, output is:

```
C:\Programm\eclipseJEE
```

Which is a folder for eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
File f = new File(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("goods.props").toURI()).getAbsolutePath();
```